# remove commas/quotation marks in column name in pandas or sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I am trying to pull some columns from a snowflake table using python/sqlalchemy into a pandas dataframe and subsequently do additional operations using Python/Pandas.

However, it appears that the resulting dataframe has some quotation marks/commas in the column names.

Code follows below:

```
  sql = '''SELECT 'concept_name', 'ndc'
         FROM db.schema.tbl'''

  df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

  df.columns.to_list()  #print out column names
```

This is the output I get for column names: ["'CONCEPT_NAME'", "'NDC'"]

How do I remove the special characters in each column name either in SQL itself or in pandas?

Comment: You wrote `'''SELECT 'concept_name', 'ndc' FROM db.schema.tbl'''`. What do you get if you omit the quotes? `'''SELECT concept_name, ndc FROM ...'''` (I am **hoping** that single-quotes are not literally part of your CREATE TABLE statement. Consider re-creating the table if that's the case.)

Comment: the sql query does not work when I am not using a single quote for each column name. Not sure I am able to recreate the sql table

Comment: That suggests that single-quotes _are_ part of the column name. Don't do that, it will only cause grief. DROP TABLE and re-create it with sensible column names, or do the equivalent ALTER COLUMN rename. (BTW, the sql92 quote character is a ` backtick, different from ' single-quote.)

Comment: How do I alter the column names without the single quote? I am using snowflake.

Comment: You chose not to tell us who your DB vendor is. Let's pretend it is postgres! Simply consult the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-altertable.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **str.strip** method to remove the special characters from the column names:

df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip("'"), inplace=True)

Comment: This works only partially. After the str.strip method, I ran df.columns to_list(). This returned the following output: ['CONCEPT_NAME', 'NDC'].  How do I remove the single quotes?

Comment: Maybe you need to apply the code one more time. alternatively, you can use the below code: df.columns = [col.replace("'", "") for col in df.columns]